# Only first character is passed in pinvoke string

Tags: dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a c++ dll that I am using using Pinvoke.

The method signature is as follow:

c++:

```
EXTERN_C BOOL std_call MyCppMethod(LPCSTR param1, LPCSTR param2);
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool MyCppMethod(
         /*[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]*/ string param1,
         /*[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]*/ string param2
        );
```

for technical reasons I replaced the dll with a lib, and wrapped the lib with a dll that uses EXPORTS.def file and EXPORTS declaration to export the method from the lib.
Since I have dine that I see a weird behavior. instead of getting the string in the method implementation I get only the first character.

I had tried to replace the calling convention, to use marshalAs LPCWSTR, and also tried to replace the lpcstr in the c++ decleration with char*.
non of the above helped me to solve the problem and I still get only the first character.

Why this is happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your CharSet is simply wrong.  LPCSTR requires CharSet.Ansi

Comment: Thanks. I have just figured that out :) but can you think of a reason why it didn't fail when it was a dll and not a lib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LPCSTR` is a pointer to null-terminated array of `char`, and `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` is a pointer to null-terminated array of `wchar_t`. So there is a simple mis-match.

The reason why you only received a single character is that ASCII characters, when represented  as two byte UTF-16 characters, have the ASCII value in one byte, and a zero in the other byte. When interpreted as null-terminated array of `char`, this is a string of length one. The zero byte is interpreted as the null-terminator.

You can fix it by changing either:

1. `LPCSTR` to `LPCWSTR` on the native side, or
2. `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` to `UnmanagedType.LPStr` on the managed side.

Frankly, to me it makes more sense to use Unicode these days so I would go for option 1. Indeed, since you specified `CharSet.Unicode` then there is no need for the `MarshalAs` at all. The code would look like this:

**C++**

```
BOOL std_call MyCppMethod(LPCWSTR param1, LPCWSTR param2);
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool MyCppMethod(string param1, string param2);
```

Note that I am also sceptical of your setting `SetLastError` to `true`. Does your function really call `SetLastError`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I figured that out when I changed the LPCSTR to std::string and saw in the debugger that every second byte is '0'. What I still find weird is that the same exact code worked when I had a .dll and not a lib wrapped with .dll is that possible?

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: I think not. Probably the version that worked had different code.